# How to control the default owner of php generated a file same as directory owner?

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I have a website (a magento website, the webserver is nginx:80, apache:8080, running fcgid) which is placed under the following directory structure, all of the directories are owned by mtest:mtest with 777 permission.

/home 
 
/home/mtest/ 
 
/home/mtest/public_html

I put a testing php file which can gen a txt file at the /home/mtest/public_html, the code is the following:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

When it generates the text.txt, the file permission is 644, owned by apache:apache. My question is how to make the newly generated file as same as the directory owner and permission (without modify the source code, actually i'm fixing the reports text file generated by the magento)?

Comment: After `$ sudo chmod g+s /home/mtest/public_html`, new files created in public_html should have group mtest (provided that public_html has group mtest).

Comment: @marekful, the group is changed to mtest, but the using name is still apache